# Swift Can't access Single object array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode

I am trying to access data from a json file. The problem is that some of the values are NSSingleObjectArrays (Arrays with only item) which I can't turn into strings.

```
class CarObject {
    var pictureURL: String!
    var carURL: String!
    var carPrice: String!
    required init(json: [String: AnyObject]) {
        pictureURL = json["galleryURL"] as! String
        carURL = json["viewItemURL"] as! String
        carPrice = json["currentPrice"] as! String
        }
}
```

I get the following error message:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x10a2ec548) to 'NSString' (0x109729440).

I tried to access them like this:

```
"json["galleryURL"][0] as String!"
```

but I get the following error:

```
Type 'Any?' has no subscript members
```

The values look like this:

> galleryURL = ("one value");

Do you guys know a way how to access them easily?
Thanks!

Comment: How would you "turn" an array into a string? What does that notion even mean? Isn't this like turning an elephant into a horse? What is it, precisely, that you want to _do_?

Comment: It's array. Access the object from the array like you would for any array.

Comment: "Type 'Any?' has no subscript members" would be a good search phrase. You know, just in case someone else has ever, ever had this problem before. If `json["galleryURL"]` is an array of strings, you need to _cast_ it to an array of strings so that the compiler knows this.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast things to the appropriate types first. It sounds like your values are arrays containing a single string, so something like this:

```
var pictureURL: URL

required init?(json: [String: AnyObject]) {
    guard let pictureURLString = (json["galleryURL"] as? [String])?.first,
        let pictureURL = URLComponents(string: pictureURLString)?.url else {
        return nil
    }

    self.pictureURL = pictureURL
}
```

Also, you may want to reconsider the types you're using for your properties. The `pictureURL` and `carURL` properties are URLs, so they make more sense typed as `URL`. The `carPrice` property is likely numeric, so it makes more sense as a `Double`.

Comment: What's the point of `URLComponents`? 1. The OP just wants a String, not a URL. 2. If the OP did want a URL, then why not just use `URL(string:)` instead of `URLComponents`?

Comment: `URLComponents` is the recommended way to create URLs from strings these days, because its behavior is more modern than `URL(string:)`. From the docs: "This structure parses and constructs URLs according to RFC 3986. Its behavior differs subtly from that of the URL structure, which conforms to older RFCs."

Comment: Did you read the question's code? Did you see my first note. No `URL` is needed.

Comment: The value is clearly meant to contain a URL, thus a `URL` is more appropriate type for that property than `String`. Use the correct tool for the job. I also recommend that the `carPrice` property should be a `Double` instead of a `String`.

Comment: To address your next objection: The removal of all the unnecessary implicitly-unwrapped and force-unwrapped optionals was also intentional, because minimizing those is good practice.